# Can one docker restart another one?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I have a series of containers inside a docker network, let me call them 'backend' (an nginx-django) and 'locator' (a pure python script). What I would like to achive is that, via a web request to the 'backend' docker, achive a restart of the 'locator' module.

Our current approach was to try to invoke, inside the backend, a bash console to issue a

> sudo docker-compose restart locator

but we have several permission problems.

Is there a proper way to manage, from inside one docker (in our case, 'backend') the other dockers form the network as we would do with the docker-compose commands?

Our dockers are managed via a docker-compose.yml file that looks as follows:

```
version: "3"

services:
  locator:
    container_name: base-location
    image: registry.gitlab.com/our-group/our-locator:base-location
    volumes:
      - ./configs:/configs
      - ./logs/locator:/configs/logs
      - ./sniffing:/app/sniffing
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "3788:3788"
      - "3787:80"
    networks:
      - app_network
    depends_on:
      - backend
    restart: always

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    environment:
      - prometheus_multiproc_dir=/dev/shm
    image: registry.gitlab.com/our-group/our-backend/backend:develop_fase1

    volumes:
      - ./configs:/configs
      - ./logs/backend:/app/logs
      - ./media:/app/media
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    networks:
      - app_network
    restart: always

    
networks:
  app_network:
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Arguably the cleanest approach is to have an HTTP endpoint in the locator service that causes it to exit, and then rely on Docker's restart policy to restart it.  You can't normally have one container directly manage another, and there are some significant security implications to making it possible.

Comment: @DavidMaze If docker's restart policy is the way to go, then this looks simpler. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something such as:

1. Install [Webhook](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook) on your Python "locator" image
2. Create a webhook configuration to allow the "reboot" command to be executed
3. Run the server at runtime, as well as your Python, with the configuration copied/mounted
4. Use your NGINX "backend" to route applicable HTTP commands to the "locator" Webhook HTTP server

Something like this would allow you to run any (pre-configured) command on the "locator" container via the "backend" exposed HTTP server. Obviously security etc. needs to be seriously considered though. This also removes the need for full Docker daemon control inside the container.